Getting error when importing a database using az cli?
I am importing a database using az cli but get an error:
I have manually copied the database to the azure storage account
 Here is the import script:


echo "Creating $database..."

echo "Importing sample database from $container to $database..."
 az sql db import --admin-password $password --admin-user $login  --storage-key $key -- 
 storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri 
 https://$storage.blob.core.windows.net/$container/$bacpac --name $database --resource- 
 group $resourceGroup --server $server

The database i am importing is about 230Gig
I can see it has tried to import as "General Purpose - Serverless: Standard-series (Gen5), 1 vCore"  whereas the working db should be "Standard S9: 1600 DTUs"
Can i set that value in the import ?
The error is as follows:
  'The operation failed because the database reached its size quota, SQL Error 40544. Please retry with sufficient storage allocated to complete the operation.'.'


The error you're encountering indicates that the database reached its size quota during the import process. This is because the target database service tier and performance level (in this case, General Purpose - Serverless: Standard-series Gen5, 1 vCore) does not provide sufficient resources to handle a database of approximately 230GB.
To resolve this issue, you need to specify the appropriate service tier and performance level that matches or exceeds the requirements of your database size and workload. For your case, you mentioned that the working database uses "Standard S9: 1600 DTUs." You should set the target database to this tier and performance level during the import operation.
Unfortunately, the az sql db import command does not allow you to directly specify the service tier and performance level (DTUs or vCores). Instead, you must first create a database with the desired configuration and then import the .bacpac file into this pre-configured database.
Below is an example for the same-
You need to create the database first with the necessary service tier using the az sql db create command. Specify the --service-objective parameter for DTUs or vCores.
If you already have one, just update the same as below-
az sql db update --name $env:database --resource-group $env:resourceGroup --server $env:server --service-objective S9


Once the database is created with the correct specifications, you can proceed with importing the .bacpac file.
az sql db import --admin-password $env:password \
                 --admin-user $env:login  \
                 --storage-key $env:key \
                 --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey \
                 --storage-uri https://$env:storage.blob.core.windows.net/$env:container/$env:bacpac \
                 --name $env:database \
                 --resource-group $env:resourceGroup \
                 --server $env:server


You can monitor the status of the import operation in the Azure Portal under the "Import/Export history" for your SQL database.


I have created a db with the same pricing tier and tried to import but now get the error   "'The ImportExport operation failed due to 'The host process exceeded its memory allowance. Retries will not be successful. Please use SSMS or SqlPackage to complete the operation.'.'."

Since even after choosing a higher tier, it is failing due to memory constraints to import the 230Gig bacpac file, can you try using SQL Server Management Studio, you can import a .bacpac file into an Azure SQL Database as a workaround. Or another way is you can download and install SqlPackage and execute the import command with the appropriate parameters SqlPackage /a:Import /sf:.\yourdatabase.bacpac /tsn:yourserver.database.windows.net /tdn:yourdatabase /tu:yourusername /tp:yourpassword

do i just run the sqlpackage command from dos prompt on windows ?

Yes, Cmd or PowerShell

I have tried ssms , still gives an error. I have tried sqlpackage and i get the error:     A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) and then it seems to continue , but looks like it ids frozen . I will wait a few more hours and see

I have tried everything and cant seem to get the database restored.   Do you recommend creating a VM in azure and dedicate it to restoring the database. It would be a vm that has 64Gig ram ?

Wow! this seems like a real pain.. Usually the azure way works most of the time. Sometimes when data is huge like yours it may suffer that's when we try via Sql server mgmt. For you everything seems to be failing.. Let me see what I can dig up for you. Is this the entire error message you got which you shared above in the comment?

Yep that is the entire message. Thats what i thought , i thought the Azure way will work smoothly ? Thanks for the help ,  it really getting annoying, waiting all this time and at the end an error !

Any luck ? I have created a VM 64 bit SQL Server 2022 and tried doing it through Azure and using sqlpackage, still no luck .   To test you may need a db of that size and you may see that it gives error ?

Was looking for some similar issue, most of them suggest the steps which we already tried, Found some links, see if this helps to troubleshoot
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/import-from-bacpac-cli?view=azuresql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/666578/msg-40544-the-database-has-reached-its-size-quota

The first link have tried no difference. Will look at the second. But surely it should be able to import from Azure ? Could it be the database that in initially create ?

I have looked and tried the second link , still no luck . This is a real pain.

did you actually try this with a database that is 200G or more ?
